# Divide a signed integer by a power of 2

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm working on a way to divide a signed integer by a power of 2 using only binary operators (<< >> + ^ ~ & | !), and the result has to be round toward 0. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061093/dividing-by-power-of-2-using-bit-shifting) also on Stackoverflow on the problem, however, I cannot understand why it works. Here's the solution:

```
int divideByPowerOf2(int x, int n)
{
    return (x + ((x >> 31) & ((1 << n) + ~0))) >> n;
}
```

I understand the `x >> 31` part (only add the next part if `x` is negative, because if it's positive `x` will be automatically round toward 0). But what's bothering me is the `(1 << n) + ~0` part. How can it work?

Comment: two's complement. But you're right, the answer doesn't explain anything. Now you get downvotes when you do that ...

Comment: `x + ~0` is a funny way to write `x - 1`, it's just to truncate that rounding mask to `n` bits

Comment: 1) Concerned about dividing negative numbers? 2) Concerned about dividing negative numbers portably?  3) Concerned about handling `x == INT_MIN`?  4) what about powers of 2 that meet/exceed the bit width of `int`?  Otherwise the goal is so narrow that it is not that useful beyond a narrow idea of the possibility or the range and details of `int`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming 2-complement, just bit-shifting the dividend is equivalent to a certain kind of division: not the conventional division where we round the dividend to next multiple of divisor toward zero. But another kind where we round the dividend toward negative infinity. I rediscovered that in Smalltalk, see http://smallissimo.blogspot.fr/2015/03/is-bitshift-equivalent-to-division-in.html.

For example, let's divide -126 by 8. traditionally, we would write

```
-126 = -15 * 8 - 6
```

But if we round toward infinity, we get a positive remainder and write it:

```
-126 = -16 * 8 + 2
```

The bit-shifting is performing the second operation, in term of bit patterns (assuming 8 bits long int for the sake of being short):

```
1000|0010 >> 3 = 1111|0000
1000|0010      = 1111|0000 * 0000|1000 + 0000|0010
```

So what if we want the traditional division with quotient rounded toward zero and remainder of same sign as dividend? Simple, we just have to add 1 to the quotient - if and only if the dividend is negative and the division is inexact.

You saw that `x>>31` corresponds to first condition, dividend is negative, assuming int has 32 bits.

The second term corresponds to the second condition, if division is inexact.

See how are encoded -1, -2, -4, ... in two complement: 1111|1111 , 1111|1110 , 1111|1100. So the negation of nth power of two has n trailing zeros.

When the dividend has n trailing zeros and we divide by 2^n, then no need to add 1 to final quotient. In any other case, we need to add 1.

What ((1 << n) + ~0) is doing is creating a mask with n trailing ones.

The n last bits don't really matter, because we are going to shift to the right and just throw them away. So, if the division is exact, the n trailing bits of dividend are zero, and we just add n 1s that will be skipped. On the contrary, if the division is inexact, then one or more of the n trailing bits of the dividend is 1, and we are sure to cause a carry to the n+1 bit position: that's how we add 1 to the quotient (we add 2^n to the dividend). Does that explain it a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

This is "write-only code": instead of trying to understand the code, try to create it by yourself.

For example, let's divide a number by 8 (shift right by 3).
If the number is negative, the normal right-shift rounds in the wrong direction. Let's "fix" it by adding a number:

```
int divideBy8(int x)
{
    if (x >= 0)
        return x >> 3;
    else
        return (x + whatever) >> 3;
}
```

Here you can come up with a mathematical formula for `whatever`, or do some trial and error. Anyway, here `whatever = 7`:

```
int divideBy8(int x)
{
    if (x >= 0)
        return x >> 3;
    else
        return (x + 7) >> 3;
}
```

How to unify the two cases? You need to make an expression that looks like this:

```
(x + stuff) >> 3
```

where `stuff` is 7 for negative `x`, and 0 for positive `x`. The trick here is using `x >> 31`, which is a 32-bit number whose bits are equal to the sign-bit of `x`: all 0 or all 1. So `stuff` is

```
(x >> 31) & 7
```

Combining all these, and replacing 8 and 7 by the more general power of 2, you get the code you asked about.

---

Note: in the description above, I assume that `int` represents a 32-bit hardware register, and hardware uses two's complement representation to do right shift.

Comment: Since `x` is of type `int`, `(x >> 31)` may or may not result in all-1s when `x` is negative. The ISO C standard states (e.g. C99 section 6.5.7, paragraph 5) that right-shifting a signed integer of negative value invokes *implementation-defined* behavior.

Comment: implementation defined behaviour can be fixed by casting to unsigned, also this solution breaks if it is shifting by 0.

Answer (score 0):

OP's reference is of a `C#` code and so many subtle differences that cause it to be *bad code* with C, as this post is tagged.

`int` is not necessarily 32-bits so using a magic number of 32 does not make for a robust solution.

In particular `(1 << n) + ~0` results in implementation defined behavior when `n` causes a bit to be shifted into the sign place. Not good coding.

Restricting code to only using "binary" operators `<< >> + ^ ~ & | !` encourages a coder to *assume* things about `int` which is not portable nor compliant with the C spec.  So OP's posted code does not "work" in general, although may work in many common implementations.

OP code fails when `int` is not 2's complement, not uses the range `[-2147483648 .. 2147483647]` or when `1 << n` uses implementation behavior that is not as expected.

```
// weak code
int divideByPowerOf2(int x, int n) {
  return (x + ((x >> 31) & ((1 << n) + ~0))) >> n;
}
```

A simple alternative, assuming `long long` exceeds the range of `int` follows.  I doubt this meets *some* corner of OP's goals, but OP's given goals encourages non-robust coding.

```
int divideByPowerOf2(int x, int n) {
  long long ill = x;
  if (x < 0) ill = -ill;
  while (n--) ill >>= 1;
  if (x < 0) ill = -ill;
  return (int) ill;
}
```